# Get ID of Dask worker from within a task

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

Is there a worker ID, or some unique identifier that a dask worker can access programmatically from within a task?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use the `get_worker` function to access the worker that you're on currently, and then grab the `id` attribute.

```
from dask.distributed import get_worker
get_worker().id
```